# Is there any other positional or dimensional property available in DOM that's not in the list?

Tags: javascript, dom

I'm compiling a list of all properties regarding size and position that are available via javascript DOM api. Please take a look..

```
console.log($0.offsetWidth)
console.log($0.clientWidth)
console.log($0.scrollWidth)
console.log($0.getBoundingClientRect().width)
console.log(getComputedStyle($0).width)
console.log($0.clientLeft)
console.log($0.offsetLeft)
console.log($0.scrollLeft)
console.log(innerWidth)
console.log(outerWidth)
console.log(screenX, pageXOffset)
console.log(screenLeft)
console.log(screen.availWidth)
console.log(screen.width)
```

what else?

only criteria is that it can be used now, not a property that is no longer available in the browsers, doesn't matter if it's marked for deprecation, as they tend to be around decades.

Also UI visualization of all of them would be great

Comment: I suggest you take a look at the [IDL index of the CSSOM view spec](https://drafts.csswg.org/cssom-view/#idl-index), which lists one or two others.

Comment: Epic find, I'll comb through and get back if I find something new. There are some mouse events etc but those are not relevant.

Comment: beside props related to mouse i didn't find anything new